# C++ - Is it better to use references in for loops?

Tags: c++, loops

If I have something like this :
`vector<string> v{"lorem", "ipsum"};`

Is it better to do my loop like this :
`for(string s : v){ ... }`

or like this :
`for(string &s : v){ ... }`

So my question is, does this type of loop duplicate the data (and so it's better to use a reference) or not ?

Comment: Obviously copying each individual string has its cost. Most of the time, you're better off with a (const?) reference

Comment: `string const & s : ...`, if it's not changing, it should be const

Comment: Btw using const reference doesn't make much sense for small POD types like int and pointers. But for the objects that might contain costly copy constructors it's better. That's also why ++something is preffered over  something++ in the c++ if you don't need the old value.

Comment: Naturally enough, it depends on what the loop is doing.   If the loop body needs a modifiable copy of the string it is working on, without changing the vector's elements, then `for (string s: z)` is an appropriate option.   If the loop is intended to modify elements of the vector then `for (string &s: v)` is an appropriate option.   If the loop just needs to read the value of vector elements, `for (const string &s : v)` may be appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are functionally very different

Try this

```
vector<string> v{ "lorem", "ipsum" };
for (string s : v) { s = "dd"; }
cout << v[0];
for (string& s : v) { s = "yy"; }
cout << v[0];
```

you will see that the first one gives you a copy of the element

The second on a reference to the element in the vector.

So which one to use really comes down to what are you trying to do.

If you are just reading then the second one is better since it doesnt create a copy (I am sure string is very efficient in this case, but its true for the general case)